# responsive css circle with two text lines

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, geometry

I am trying to make a **responsive** circle in CSS.

- It has to be activated as a **link**.
- When you **hover** over the circle, the **background color** needs to change.
- In some circles there need to be **two text lines**.

I found this example script. But unfortunately it is not a link yet:
http://codeitdown.com/css-circles/

As well the following example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cqoFv. Which is not a link yet as well.

So, only the circle needs to be a link.

Your help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Some like this?
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zAaGe

Just easy css.
:hover,visited.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Do you have a suggestion for the two text lines? So it will not become an egg...